# Can not figure out how to delete local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I tried making a reset button to delete everything but when you refresh page the list reappears...Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/12/

EDITL: Sorry, you are right, stupid me I forgot to change my storage's name...duh..haha...thanks a lot! I am not very familiar with html 5, still learning it.

```
    var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage["numbers"] || "[]");
for(var i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
    storage.removeItem('saved[i]');
    add(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` has two ways to remove data:

```
storage.removeItem('key'); // remove one item
storage.clear();           // remove everything
```

Comment: @Jeff Hodge - it works, I just tried it with ___your___ script.  `localStorage.removeItem('numbers')` or `localStorage.clear()` ___both___ work.